# How do you set no timeout for a specific remap?

Tags: visual-mode, key-bindings, keyboard-layout

The question arise from a problem using a huge remapped configuration so [bépo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#B.C3.89PO) layout is virtually the same as the qwerty in normal mode, at least for single key press commands.

Selecting text using visual selection mode, then pressing `i` which is configured as `noremap i d`, it would be expected that the text would be immediately deleted. But it isn't immediately triggered, instead it's waiting for a possible second key.

Setting `timeoutlen` to zero will achieve the expected result in this context, but then a command like `,,` which is configured as `noremap ,, gg` won't work anymore.

So is it possible to set timeout specific to one command, or in certain context like in visual selection mode with an active selection?

Maybe having `timeoutlen` turned to zero might make things like `noremap ,, gg` useless, so just removing this mapping might be enough to achieve the expected result.

Comment: How about setting it to a reasonable value, like, say 500? For the modes, AFAICT there autocmd events only for insert-mode-related events, so it might not be possible (unless you use `CursorMoved` and monitor for changes to modes, but that's error-prone and too much overhead).

Comment: I have never used another keyboard layout, but since I have seen this before: What you mean with hugely remapped ? From this article on Dvorak (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout) I get the guess, that it should work quite well with the langmap command (Except multibutton commands like <c-v>). Sorry if this is what you already have done. Like i said, never needed it, but I hope it may help you.

Comment: I mean [this mapping](https://bepo.fr/wiki/Vim#B.C3.A9po.2FQwerty).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have something like

```
noremap i d
noremap ix ... other mappings starting with i
```

And you are asking that for `i` the timeout is 0.

In that case you would never be able to type any of the `ix` mappings - so why not just remove them and solve the problem this way?

If this is only for visual mode then avoid defining mappings that start with `i` for that mode.

You can remove the mappings you mentioned in the comments with

```
xunmap iM
xunmap im
```

Comment: Actually, the problem concern the visual selection mode, sorry for the error and thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: @psychoslave you can do `:map i` to see which mappings are defined for what modes.

Comment: ```x  iM          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>30_wrap_i('[[','][')<CR>                 
o  iM          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>30_wrap_i('[[','][')<CR>                 
x  im          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>30_wrap_i('[m',']M')<CR>                 
o  im          *@:<C-U>call <SNR>30_wrap_i('[m',']M')<CR>                 
   i           * d  
```

Comment: Hard to read this way, you should update your question. `x` stands for visual mode - so you should remove the `iM` and `im` mappings.